# How to make updater for GameMaker Game

Tags: game-maker

I am using **GameMaker**. The game I am working on will need to be updated later on. How would I create an updater so people don't have to download the updated version. I would like it so the person playing it can push a button and the game update.

Answer (score 2):

I have done it.

I created a file on a server, basically it can be every server. In this file I said:

```
[Version]
Version = 1010
```

So the newest version is 1.0.1.0. There is a function GM_version to check the current version of the game, but ot would return 1.0.0.1, I don't know why they done this.
So, in order to fix this, this is my create event:

```
//Re-order version and delete points
Version3 = string_replace(GM_version,'.','')
Point1 = string_pos('.',version3)
Version2 = string_delete(version3,point1,1)
Point2 = string_pos('.',version2)
Version1 = string_delete(version2,point2,1)
String1 = string_copy(version1,point1,point2 - point1)
Version0 = string_delete(version1,point1,point2 - point1)

Version_local = version0 + string1


//Delete old file and get serverfile
Version_online = 0
Got = 0
file_delete("your file")
File = http_get_file("your serverfile","your file")
```

In the Asynchronous HTTP Event is this code:

```
if ds_map_find_value(async_load,"id") == file {
    if ds_map_find_value(async_load,"status") == 0 {
        ini_open("your file")
        Version_online = ini_read_string("version","version",version_local)
        ini_close()
        Got = 1
    }
}
```

Last, in the step event:

```
if got == 1 {
    if version_online > version_local {
        //your code when there's an update, e.g. open your homepage.
    }
    Got = 0
}
```

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't do that in pure GM, and the easiest solution is to do it in another language and just launch it with GM.

---

You can't update a part of the game as it will be compiled to a single executable. Users will have to download the whole .exe of your game. Your best bet is to create another standalone program (with GM or another software/language). You can always launch that updater program through a button click in your game. You might find open-source code to make your own updater in C, C++ or C#.

If I were you, I would just make a small button "check for update" in the game and it would lead to a PHP website with the current version in the address (e.g. `www.mygamesite/update?v=1.2345`). Then you make the website compare the version passed in the URL to show either "your game is up to date" or "download the latest version" with a changelist.